Automate fetching for bare git repository
I have set up a bare repository for a team to push their code to. I've noticed in order for the team to get the latest version of remote repo, I need to do git fetch branch:branch to update the bare repo. I wonder if there exists anyway that I get this command to execute whenever someone pull from my bare repo?
I have limited knowledge about this issue, but I have heard of git hooks as a way to trigger an event when a specific action takes place, so I guess I will write a script to execute above command inside an appropriate file in hooks directory, I don't know which one would it be though, or if this is a correct approach at all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
